# Handle imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, imbalanced-data

I am trying to handle the imbalance dataset with proportion 1:3, where number labels 0 takes more proportion, and use upsampling technique for labels 1.

As the dataset is about predicting heart disease, I want to maximize recall rather than precision and the result is opposite what I want.
I wonder if I use/implement my technique incorrectly?

Those are my function for balanced dataset

```
def cost(y, y_predict):
  """
  Params:
  ------
  y (m, 1): vector containing m target values
  y_predict (m, 1): vector containing m predicted values
  ------
  Returns:
  ------
  loss (scalar)
  """
  return np.mean(- y * np.log(y_predict) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_predict)) 


def calculate_gradient(y, y_predict, x):
  """
  Params:
  ------
  y (m, 1): vector containing m target values
  y_predict (m, 1): vector containing m predicted values
  x (m, n): matrix containing m records with n features
  ------
  Returns:
  ------
  gradient (n, 1): dJ / d(theta)
  """
  return np.dot(x.T, (y_predict - y)) / x.shape[1]
```

Those are my cost functions after modifying

```
# Modified functions
def modified_cost(y, y_predict, ratio=3):
  """
  Deal with imbalanced data 
  ------
  Params:
  ------
  y (m, 1): vector containing m target values
  y_predict (m, 1): vector containing m predicted values
  ratio (float): ratio of 0 bias to 1 bias 
  ------
  Returns:
  ------
  loss (scalar)
  """
  return - np.mean((ratio * y * np.log(y_predict) + (1 - y) * np.log(1 - y_predict)))


def modified_calculate_gradient(y, y_predict, x, ratio=3):
  """
  Params:
  ------
  y (m, 1): vector containing m target values
  y_predict (m, 1): vector containing m predicted values
  x (m, n): matrix containing m records with n features
  ratio (float): ratio of 0 bias to 1 bias 
  ------
  Returns:
  ------
  gradient (n, 1): dJ / d(theta)
  """
  return - np.dot(x.T, (ratio * y - y_predict + (1 - ratio) * y * y_predict)) / x.shape[1]
```

Before I try upsampling technique for labels 1
[image: Before I tried upsampling technique for labels 1]

After I handled imbalanced dataset

[image: After I handled imbalanced dataset]

Comment: Class imbalance is such a common source of confusion that we have a [statistics meta post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274) discussing the topic. You might be interested in the discussion there that links to posts about why proper statistical methods have no issue with class imbalance (except in a few cases, but these tend not to be the times when class imbalance comes up as an issue for a machine learning problem).

Comment: @Dave thank you for your valuable recommendation. I think I really need to read more about class imbalance